# Rewriting an if statement which throws an exception in a cleaner way

Tags: java, option-type, predicate, code-cleanup

Let's suppose we have an if statement like this:

```
public A save(A a) {
    if (isValid.test(a)) {
        return aRepository.save(a);
    }
    throw new ANotValidException("A is not valid");
}
```

`isValid` is a Predicate and it may look like:

```
private Predicate<A> isValid = (a) -> (a != null);
```

What do you think? Can I make it cleaner somehow? 
I mean, for example using an `Optional` to reduce it in 1 line with an `.orElseThrow();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more precise version using `Optional` and `throw`ing a custom `Exception` shall be :

```
public A save(A a) throws ANotValidException { // throws the custom exception
    return Optional.ofNullable(a) // since your predicate is to check for not null 
                   .map(aRepository::save)
                   .orElseThrow(() -> new ANotValidException(a + "A is not valid"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `Optional` can make the code more readable, particularly around the use of your predicate object:

```
public A save(A a) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(a)
            .filter(isValid)
            .map(aRepository::save)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ANotValidException("A is not valid"));
}
```

You can also get rid of the predicate altogether as it's simple enough to use `Objects::nonNull` (unless your real predicate's test is more complex). And in that case, keeping your current condition checks would probably make more sense (in my opinion).

Comment: @khelwood That sounds like the start of a debate. I think yes (unless the OP doesn't use a predicate object, using an optional is more natural here). But that's my opinion. I suspect yours is different :-) - but that's all beside the point. I believe the question is about how to use Optional to do the same thing (as one can infer from wording and tags)

Comment: I suppose this change means that the method needs to take an `Optional<A>` as argument instead of  `A` (and the same with the predicate) or have I missed something?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No. The optional is being created inline. The internet advises against using `Optional` as a method parameter type. The predicate must be a class variable (the way it's used in the question implies that)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I had made a typo in my code which made me believe I needed Optional.

Answer (score 1):

One could argue that it would be more natural to read it in the opposite order, that is first handle the validation and the result of it and then move on to saving the object.

```
public A save(A a) {
    if (!isValid.test(a)) {
        throw new ANotValidException("A is not valid");
    }

    return aRepository.save(a);
}
```